# Not sure how to handle this simple recursion with fractions

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a simple recursion method to calculate `m(i) = (1/2) + (2/3) + ... + i/(i+1)`. I feel like this should be incredibly simple, but I cannot figure it out. I know that I have to loop by decrementing, but I just can't get it. So far I have the following, which I know is completely wrong.

```
public class Recursion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double n = run(10);
        System.out.print("Result: " + n);
    }

    public static double run(double nb) {
        double result = 0;

        if(nb == 2){
            return 1/2;
        }

        result += run(nb - 2) / run(nb - 1);
        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: Never compare double values using `==`. 2 floating point values (almost) never equal.

Comment: @AlexR - Unless the numbers are very large, add, subtract, and multiply of doubles that happen to be exact integer values will produce exact integer values. Furthermore, comparing double values that are known to be exact integers (as in this case) can be safely done using `==`. (However, double values don't need to be compared at all; see my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this recurrence relation:

> m(i) = i/(i+1) + m(i-1)

In code, it might look like this:

```
public static double run(int i) {
    if (i < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return i / (i + 1.0) + run(i - 1);
}
```

Note that there's no need for the argument to be floating point, just the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class Recursion{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double n = run(10);
        System.out.print("Result: " + n);
    }

    public static double run(double nb) {
        double result = 0;
        if(nb > 1){
            result = nb/(nb + 1) + run(nb - 1);
        } else{
            result = nb/(nb + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're off with your terminating condition. The recursion will overflow the stack if `nb < 2` and it returns the wrong value for `nb == 2` (returning 1/2 when it should return 7/6).

Comment: That's exactly the problem I'm getting, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

trying a bit math should make this simple.

> m(i) = 1/2 + 2/3 +....+(i)/(i+1)
>   or m(i) = 2/2-1/2 + 3/3-1/3 + ....+ (i+1)/(i+1) - 1/(i+1)
>    or m(i) = 1-1/2 + 1 - 1/3 +...(i times)..+ 1 - (1/(i+1))
>    or m(i) = i - ( 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(i+1) )

Now it should be easy to write a algorithm for this.

Comment: How does this help with writing a recursive solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this

```
result += run(nb - 2) / run(nb - 1);
```

By

```
result += nb - 2 / nb - 1;
return result + run(nb - 1);
```